# URL Encode functions after asking for input

Tags: c#, html, urlencode, urldecode

I have this website I am using `https://www.examplewebsiteone.com/account/verify?email=testeremail%40gmail%2Ecom&password=this%26isjust%26a%26test%24`

this is what is look like **decoded** 
https://www.examplewebsiteone.com/account/verify?email=testeremail@gmail.com
&password=this&isjust&a&test$

Encoded by https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

My C# Code:

```
private const string URL = "https://www.examplewebsiteone.com/account/verify?email=testeremail%40gmail%2Ecom&password=this%26isjust%26a%26test%24";
private const string DATA = @"{""object"":{""name"":""Name""}}";

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Class1.CreateObject();
}
```

I want to **ask for user input** (email)(password).  When user enters `testeremail@gmail.com` (email) and `this&isjust&a&test$` (password) then I want c# to **encode** the regular text with "Windows-1252 or UTF 8 whatever" **like in example above**. And **use the input in URL string above**. Please help, I am new to C#.

Comment: `HttpUtility.UrlEncode("this&isjust&a&test$")`

Comment: That kind of encoding is URL encoding, not UTF-8 or Windows 1252.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `UrlEncode()` and `UrlDecode()` methods of `Httputility` which is in `System.Web` namespace:

```
string encoded = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Url);
string decode = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(encoded);
```